# my array remains 'undefined' after array.push()

Tags: javascript, arrays, titanium, label, push

this is my code

```
var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'mobile_db.js'); // Local File Read
Ti.include(f.nativePath);

var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth : 'auto',
    contentHeight : 'auto',
    showVerticalScrollIndicator : true,
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator : false,
    layout : 'vertical',
    height : '100%',
    width : '100%',

});

function sortObject(obj) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            arr.push({
                'key' : prop,
                'value' : obj[prop]
            });
        }
    }
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.value - b.value;
    });
    return arr;
}

var arr = sortObject(data);
var lblArr = [];
var roctje = [];

var alertDialog = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
    title: 'ffs error?',
    message: 'Do you want to do this?',
    buttonNames: ['Yes','Sparta?','No'],
    cancel: 1
});

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (data[i].instelling_title == "ROC") {
        roctje.push(data[i].instelling_title);
    }
    else if (data[i].instelling_title == "Scalda") {
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    else {
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    lblArr[i] = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text : roctje[i] + ' ' + ' - ' + ' ' + ' ' + ' ' + adresArray[i].address_street + ' ' + adresArray[i].address_housenr + ' ' + adresArray[i].address_postalcode + ' ' + adresArray[i].address_city + ' ' + adresArray[i].address_country,
        color : 'black',
        top : '15',
        width : '85%'
    });
    scrollView.add(lblArr[i]);
}

var viewqq = Ti.UI.createView({
    borderRadius : 10,
    top : 10,
    height : 2000,
    width : 'auto'
});

Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(viewqq);
scrollView.add(viewqq);
Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(scrollView);
Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(viewqq);
```

My the array i want to push :

```
var data = [
     {item: 'SCALDA 1', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {item: '14', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {item: '15', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '16', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '17', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '18', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '19', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: 'ROC22', instelling_title: 'ROC', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '21', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '22', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '13', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '12', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '3', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '4', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '5', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '6', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '799', instelling_title: 'ROC', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '8', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '9', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '10', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '11', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
     {instelling_id: '23', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''}
];
```

When i load the data out of the array(roctje) all it'll say inside the app is Undifined. My guess is that the array is empty, not sure though. Can anyone help me out :p?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You're passing in `data` which is an array of objects into `sortObject`, and then you're looping over the array like you would an object, creating a new object that has a key property that matches the array index, and having each input array object as a value property. You're then trying to sort on the value property (objects) which you can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure from the question, but from observation I can see in the for loop u have used `data` as an array instead of `arr` which is the array.

`data` is an object which you have passed to get `arr`.